# ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid in UsersController#show

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, oracle

It's impossible to go to this address: 127.0.0.1/users/sign_up.
When I go to the page, I get the following error:

```
OCIError: ORA-01722: invalid number: SELECT * FROM (SELECT "BLACKROW"."V_B_USERS".* FROM "BLACKROW"."V_B_USERS" WHERE (USER_ID = 'sign_up') ORDER BY "BLACKROW"."V_L_USERS"."USER_ID" ASC ) WHERE ROWNUM <= 1
```

On this action there is an error:

```
# Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.

    def set_user
      @user = User.where('USER_ID = ?', params[:id]).first
    end
```

What's wrong? And how can this be remedied?

Comment: `USER_ID = 'sign_up'`? what's in the params?, maybe you're not sending a "real" id value.

Answer (score 0):

```
... WHERE (USER_ID = 'sign_up')
```

"ID" usually (once again: *usually*) means a NUMBER. If you have a look at the V_L_USERS table, what does it say - what is USER_ID data type? If it really is a NUMBER, then using a string (which 'sign_up' is) against it will raise the INVALID NUMBER error.

Answer (score 0):

It seems it's an issue with your ID parameter.

Side note: a cleaner way to find the user would be with Users.find(params[:id])